# Annoying lag when jQuery UI template is loading

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, layout

I have web service that uses jQuery UI elements (mostly buttons).

I write all code in document.ready() part of code is separate js file. What make me furious is 0,5 s between start loading page and end of loading when all buttons have ugly html default style. I havn't senn it on other web pages so I thins I am doing something wrong...

How to prevent that?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#radio").buttonset();
   $("#mapcontrols").buttonset();
}
```

Comment: Have you got a lot of large images or content loading first - your buttons will only be styled once the page has finished loading completely

Comment: @Pete - you're thinking of `$(document).load()`.  Ready fires when the DOM has loaded, which is before images load

Comment: ah yeah, but it still waits until your document is ready so if there is something on the page that is taking a while to process then the buttons won't be styled until that has finished

Comment: Yup. Page needs do fire google maps app and it takes a while...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hide them at DOM loading and when all set then show them.

```
$(window).load(function() { // will fire handler when all content on document is on position
   $(".radio, .mapcontrols").hide().buttonset(); // first hide and then apply method buttonset() to it
   $(".radio, .mapcontrols").fadeIn();
});
```

And use classes if you have multiple buttons.